# Powerbi refresh issue

Tags: powerbi

When I refresh the powerbi report in powerbi service, I end up getting an empty table.

When I refresh it in powerbi desktop, I don't have any issues refreshing. In the online environment, powerbi service, I get the report initially on first upload. When I refresh the dataset and the report I end up getting the empty table shown or a summarized version.

First I thought this would be a datatype issue, so I changed the week of year to the start date of that week, but that also didn't work. I tried both a date table of my own and an external one, both gave me the same issue.

Any suggestions on what I can try to make this work? Perhaps a different way to display weeks in powerbi? Thanks in advance.

- [failed refresh 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLpmA.png)
- [failed refresh 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ3bQ.png)
- [how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIanP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

When I extracted the data to powerbi I then transformed the date from date/time to date in powerbi. This seemed to have caused the refresh to mess up.

Once I deleted the transformation and then changed my separate date table to date/time aswell, I reuploaded the report and it no longer showed a bad refresh.